# how to change Hadoop Log Dir Prefix from /var/log/hadoop to /home/hadoop/log/hadoop by ambari

Tags: hadoop

my friends

Anybody knows how to change Hadoop Log Dir Prefix  from /var/log/hadoop to /home/hadoop/log/hadoop by ambari [![enter image description here][1]][1]

hadoop2.4    ambari

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. login to the ambari server
2. Stop the service which you wish to change.
3. use `configs.sh @ /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/` with proper arguments to change what ever default configuration you wish to change.
4. `./configs.sh -u $adminuser -p $password -port $ambariport [set|get|delete] $ambariserverfqdn $clustername $env $attribute $value`
5. Restart the service.
6. assuming all default user/password/port: the can be changed with: `./configs.sh set $ambariserverfqdn $cluster hdfs-env hdfs_log_dir_prefix "/home/hadoop/log/hadoop"`